# How to add a external JavaScript into a Express file?

Tags: node.js, express, qr-code

How can I add this [qr-code](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/) made by David Shim into my express app so that I can generate a QR Code for details of the user and display it into my template engine (handle-bars)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)) 

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
let sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
let query = myDB.query(sql, (err, results) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Success")
  res.render('index',{
    results: results
  });
});
});
```